# In pandas dataframe, clean output after calculating the mean of a Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, mean

This may be simple enough, but I can't find my way out. I have a pandas dataframe with numbers and I want to just take the mean in order to produce a plot. So, I attempt the following:

```
df['Numbers'].mean()

Out[83]: Timedelta('2516 days 21:36:00')
```

I just want the number, i.e. 2516, without the "days" and the "21:36:00" info that keeps appearing as above, and which I have no idea why they come up. Can you help me please?

Comment: `df['Numbers'].mean().days`?

Comment: Or even better `df['Numbers'].mean() / pd.Timedelta('1D')`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: @Leonardo its `TimeDelta` format, internally it formats your TimeDelta string and adds days into it. Nothing to worry about as internally you have `TimeDelta` object. You can access the parameters using [`dt.components`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.components.html#pandas.Series.dt.components)